# Modify default description style

Tags: lists, description

I need to modify description style. I want the description entry to be on the next line, with a different color and

```
\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
    \let\olditem\item% 
    \begin{list}{}{
        \renewcommand\item[2][]{
            \olditem \textbf{\textsc{\color{black}{##1}}} \\ \normalfont \color{light-gray} ##2
        }
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.05em}
        \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.8em}
        }
}
{
    \end{list}%
}
```

My problem is the extra space between the first and the second letters of the description.

I am not able to post an image as it is my first post.

Comment: If you put a (MWE) we can put the image for you.

Answer (score 2):

[What you want to do is described here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35481/215)

That said, the explanation of the odd spaces is that LaTeX
puts spaces at newlines. So if you see spurious spaces, the first thing to try is adding `%` to the end of the lines in your definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
    \let\olditem\item% 
    \begin{list}{}{
        \renewcommand\item[2][]{
            \olditem\textbf{\textsc{\color{black}{##1}}}\\%
            \normalfont \color{red}##2%
        }%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.05em}
        \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.8em}
        }
}
{
    \end{list}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
  \item [Something] More things
  \item [foo] Bar
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

I changed to `red` because I don't know where `light-gray` was defined.