# How can I force all text to continue to the next line when using style=nextline in description lists with enumitem?

Tags: lists, margins, enumitem

This question is related to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69525/13552.

The documentation for `enumitem` (on page 7 in Version 3.5.2 2011-09-28) says that

> nextline: if the label does not fit in the margin, the text continues in the next line,
>   otherwise it is placed in a box of width \leftmargin − \labelsep, i.e., the item body
>   never sticks into the left margin. Sets labelwidth=!.

My goal would be to get all text to continue onto the next line regardless of the label's width.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[description]{style=nextline} % Optional Global Setup

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline] % Local Setup
  \item [Green] The color green.
  \item [Red] The color red.
  \item [Yellow] The color yellow.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't that what happens in your example code?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina True. I need to find a way to replicate a scenario where the label DOES fit into the margin at least once in a minimal example. Nonetheless, the issue is still there.

Comment: If you change `\item [Green] The color green.` to `\item [G] The color g.` in your example code. one can see the effect you want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `leftmargin` to `0pt` so nothing can fit there and the new line is forced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[description]{style=nextline,leftmargin=0pt} % Optional Global Setup

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=0pt] % Local Setup
  \item [Green] The color green.
  \item [Red] The color red.
  \item [Yellow] The color yellow.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, allowing you to have indentation for the description texts is to set `labelwidth` to `0pt` (with `style=nextline` this always forces a new line), and then control other lengths such as `leftmargin` and `itemindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Optional Global Setup

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some test text
\begin{description}[style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax] % Local Setup
  \item[Green]The color green.
  \item[Red] The color red.
  \item[Yellow] The color yellow.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Actually I thought about that, but it is not aesthetically pleasing. +1 for working solution though! Maybe I will end up going for this option if I cannot find a better solution.

Comment: @macmadness86 What would you consider an "aesthetically pleasing" solution? Please explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Exactly the same indentation as the default description list with style=nextline enabled. More importantly, I think the ability to control indentation is important and should not be sacrificed.

Comment: @macmadness86 I see your point. Please see my updated answer.