# How can I force 'description' to start on a new line when using 'enumerate'?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, lists, enumitem

I want to use the `description` environment with the actual description starting on a new line. As https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69525/293290 suggests, I am using the `enumitem` package and I have set `style=nextline`. But it doesn't work when the description is another environment, in my case `enumerate`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[Offset]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First line.
            \item Second line.
            \item Third line.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: The rendered code snipped showing bad offset.]

I've tried to insert a space in between, but it made a giant space.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[Offset]~
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First line.
            \item Second line.
            \item Third line.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of big space.]

I have searched for other solutions and I came across *[How can I force all text to continue to the next line when using style=nextline in description lists with enumitem?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262364/293290)*, but this also doesn't solve my problem. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get what you want is to simply add a small negative vertical space at the beginning of the embedded `enumerate` list. We can do this using the `before` key which can inject code before the list starts. I've also added `leftmargin=*` to the list parameters so that the numbering lines up with the unnumbered description items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[First line] This is the first line.
    \item[Second line]
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,before*=\leavevmode\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}]
            \item First line.
            \item Second line.
            \item Third line.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I believe this is the best solution. Description items which don't start with `enumerate` or `itemize` won't be affected at all which is an improvement over the other solution posted here (but both solutions work). Thanks!

Comment: @user13840624 As far as I can tell the other solution doesn't actually work.