# customising second line indent

Tags: indentation

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.5 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs 
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.10} %line spacing
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*.}}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]

\item blah 1 222dfhkvnuittvriebvnytbyrteoy marcus polo texas polo fg polo polo marco bolo marco bolo marco bolo marco bolo
\item blah 2

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This gives

1. blah 1 222dfhkvnuittvriebvnytbyrteoy marcus polo texas polo fg polo polo marco bolo marco bolo marco bolo marco bolo.
2. blah 2

However intend to start the second line of each item from below the item number. Secondly how to adjust space between item number and start of the item

Answer (score 1):

> However intend to start the second line of each item from below the item number.

Maybe this link helps. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680058/278534

> Secondly how to adjust space between item number and start of the item

Use `labelsep=` locally at the start of the list structure environment or globally within `\setlist`. For `\setlist` see section 5 of the `enumitem https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf

For example, you could use `\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=2em}` in the preamble after loading the `enumitem` package or, in the document body, `\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=2em]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.5 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs 
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.10} %line spacing
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=2em}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*.}}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.},labelsep=2em]

\item blah 1 222dfhkvnuittvriebvnytbyrteoy marcus polo texas polo fg polo polo marco bolo marco bolo marco bolo marco bolo
\item blah 2

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.5 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.10} %line spacing
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%\setlength\parindent{2pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs 
%\raggedleft


\begin{document}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*.}}

\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=20pt, labelindent=0pt]

\item \kant[1]
\item test

\begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin=20pt, labelwidth=20pt, labelindent=23pt]
%\item \kant[3]
\item so far so good

\begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin=29pt, labelwidth=20pt, labelindent=28pt, label={(\roman*)}]
%\itemindent=0em

\item \kant[5]
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This solved the situation

Comment: I think that `wide=0pt` is more stable than just `wide`.